# How to filter through an array of objects and list all objects containing a certain keyword in one of it's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, prototype

I am working on an array of book objects and the task is to console.log a list of all books containin "companies" or "people" in their title.

```js
const books = [{
    title: 'How to win friends and influence people',
    authors: ['Dale Carnegie'],
    publisher: 'Pocket Books',
    year: '1936'
  }, {
    title: 'Management: tasks, responsibilities, practices',
    authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'],
    publisher: 'Harper Business',
    year: '1985'
  }, {
    title: 'Strength finder 2.0',
    authors: ['Tom Rath'],
    publisher: 'Gallup Press',
    year: '2007'
  }, {
    title: 'In search of excellence: Lessons from America\'s best-run companies',
    authors: ['Thomas Peters', ' Robert H. Waterman'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1982'
  }, {
    title: 'Built to last: Successful habits of visionary companies',
    authors: ['James C. Collins', 'Jerry I. Porras'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1994'
  }, {
    title: 'Reengineering the corporation: A manifesto for business revolution',
    authors: ['Michael Hammer', 'James A. Champy'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1993'
  }, {
    title: 'Competitive advantage: Creating and sustaining superior performance',
    authors: ['Michael E. Porter'],
    publisher: 'Free Press',
    year: '1998'
  }, {
    title: 'Crossing the chasm: Marketing and selling technology products to mainstream customers',
    authors: ['Geoffrey A. Moore', 'Regis McKenna'],
    publisher: 'Pocket Books',
    year: '1936'
  }, {
    title: '7 habits of highly effective people: Powerful lessons in personal change',
    authors: ['Stephen R. Covey'],
    publisher: 'Simon and Shuster',
    year: '1990'
  }, {
    title: 'The Six Sigma Way',
    authors: ['Peter S. Pande et al', 'Robert P. Neuman', 'Roland R. Cavanagh'],
    publisher: 'McGraw Hill',
    year: '2000'
  }, {
    title: 'The innovator\'s dilemma: When new technologies cause great firms to fail',
    authors: ['Clayton M. Christensen'],
    publisher: 'Harvard Business School Press',
    year: '1997'
  }, {
    title: 'The Essential Drucker',
    authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'],
    publisher: 'Harper Business',
    year: '2001'
  }];
```

So far I've tried using `filter()` and `includes()` as per below, but it's only returning books that contain the keyword "people"

let keyWord = books.filter (bookTitle => bookTitle.title.includes('people'||'companies'));
console.log(keyWord);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't use OR operator inside include(). So you can write the logic outside.

```
books.filter(book => book.title.includes('companies') || book.title.includes('people'))
```

If match needs to be case insensitive:

```
books.filter(book => {
    const titleLower = book.title.toLowerCase()
    return titleLower.includes('companies') || titleLower.includes('people')
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) along with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to match the desired result.

We create an array of keywords, then return any item that matches `some` of these.

```js
const books = [{ title: 'How to win friends and influence people', authors: ['Dale Carnegie'], publisher: 'Pocket Books', year: '1936' }, { title: 'Management: tasks, responsibilities, practices', authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'], publisher: 'Harper Business', year: '1985' }, { title: 'Strength finder 2.0', authors: ['Tom Rath'], publisher: 'Gallup Press', year: '2007' }, { title: 'In search of excellence: Lessons from America\'s best-run companies', authors: ['Thomas Peters', ' Robert H. Waterman'], publisher: 'Harper Collins', year: '1982' }, { title: 'Built to last: Successful habits of visionary companies', authors: ['James C. Collins', 'Jerry I. Porras'], publisher: 'Harper Collins', year: '1994' }, { title: 'Reengineering the corporation: A manifesto for business revolution', authors: ['Michael Hammer', 'James A. Champy'], publisher: 'Harper Collins', year: '1993' }, { title: 'Competitive advantage: Creating and sustaining superior performance', authors: ['Michael E. Porter'], publisher: 'Free Press', year: '1998' }, { title: 'Crossing the chasm: Marketing and selling technology products to mainstream customers', authors: ['Geoffrey A. Moore', 'Regis McKenna'], publisher: 'Pocket Books', year: '1936' }, { title: '7 habits of highly effective people: Powerful lessons in personal change', authors: ['Stephen R. Covey'], publisher: 'Simon and Shuster', year: '1990' }, { title: 'The Six Sigma Way', authors: ['Peter S. Pande et al', 'Robert P. Neuman', 'Roland R. Cavanagh'], publisher: 'McGraw Hill', year: '2000' }, { title: 'The innovator\'s dilemma: When new technologies cause great firms to fail', authors: ['Clayton M. Christensen'], publisher: 'Harvard Business School Press', year: '1997' }, { title: 'The Essential Drucker', authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'], publisher: 'Harper Business', year: '2001' }];

const keyWords = ['people', 'companies'];

function findMatchingTitles(books, keyWords) { 
    return books.filter(({title}) => { 
        return keyWords.some(keyword => title.includes(keyword));
    })
}

console.log('Matching titles:');
const result = findMatchingTitles(books, ['people', 'companies']);
result.forEach(book => console.log(book.title));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use regex:

```js
const peopleRegex = /people/i
const companiesRegex = /companies/i

const result = books.filter(item=>peopleRegex.test(item.title) || companiesRegex.test(item.title))
```

Comment: No reason to use double condition with regex, because you can merge all target values into one regex

Comment: anyway it works